# VMWare (anti) detection EXCEPTION_PRIV_INSTRUCTION?

Tags: assembly, x86, vmware, detection, privileged-functions

Is it possible to avoid VMWare detection against the following method?

I found this code is used really often:

```
            push    edx
            push    ecx
            push    ebx
    
            mov     eax, 'VMXh'
            mov     ebx, 0          // anything but 'VMXh'
            mov     ecx, 10         // get VMWare version
            mov     edx, 'VX'       // port number
            in      eax, dx         // read port
            cmp     ebx, 'VMXh'     // is it a reply from VMWare?
            je      lblInVMWare
    
            xor     ecx, ecx        // not in VMWare - clear return value
    
        lblInVMWare:
            mov     [nVersion], ecx // vmware product type
            pop     ebx
            pop     ecx
            pop     edx
```

There is a description how it works:
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9823/Detect-if-your-program-is-running-inside-a-Virtual

To be brief, that 'magic'/special port (`in eax, dx // read port`) gives something and that's impossible to run on a real computer because of the exception (privileged instruction)

According to [this article](https://www.virusbulletin.com/virusbulletin/2012/05/malware-design-strategies-circumventing-detection-and-prevention-controls-part-one#figure.3) I tried to use a few parameters in my VMX file:

```
monitor_control.disable_directexec = true"
monitor_control.disable_chksimd = "true"
monitor_control.disable_ntreloc = "true"
monitor_control.disable_selfmod = "true"
monitor_control.disable_reloc = "true"
monitor_control.disable_btinout = "true"
monitor_control.disable_brmemspace = "true"
monitor_control.disable_btpriv = "true"
monitor_control.disable_btseg = "true"
isolation.tools.getPtrLocation.disable = "true"
isolation.tools.setPtrLocation.disable = "true"
isolation.tools.setVersion.disable = "true"
isolation.tools.getVersion.disable = "true"
```

and removed VMWare Tools but failed

(I use x32dbg to see what's going on - the code works successfully on VM and doesn't give me any exceptions)

Comment: What OS is this detection code running under inside the VMWare session?

Comment: Windows 10 (x64 x86). Application is x86

Comment: See if that interface is still active with paravirtualization off.

Comment: I use VMWare Workstation 17.0.0. I didn't find this functionality. Did I understand you correctly or did I miss something?

Comment: I don't use VMWare, so I don't know. But all these auxiliary interfaces are usually used for paravirtualization. It may be that it cannot be disabled in VMWare. In that case there's really nothing you can do but try to work around the check by patching it or using a dynamic binary instrumentation framework.